# Electronic symbols standard sizes

Tags: standard, dimensions

I started to make my own eagle library with all basic parts like resistors, capacitors, inductors and so on...

I know there is a standard for electronic symbols but I couldn't find the dimensions of the symbols (for example the width and height of a resistor) (I'm talking about DIN here).

Does someone know where I can get that information?

[image]

Comment: Make them the same size as the ones in the supplied libraries. You shouldn't need to create your own symbols, anyway.

Comment: I would say it's a matter of common sense and practicality. Make sure similar components' symbols are the same size on the screen/schematic. E.g. a resistor takes up the same space as a fuse, inductor, thermistor, etc; a transistor is the same size as a MOSFET, JFET, SCR, thyristor, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [IEC 60617 (preview)](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec60617_db.pdf) :

> The meaning of a symbol is defined by its shape and by its content.
>   The size and line thickness do not affect the meaning. The minimum
>   size of a symbol shall be such that the rules for line thickness,
>   spacing of lines, lettering, etc. can be applied. Within these
>   constraints, the symbols intended for installation diagrams and
>   network maps may be enlarged or reduced to suit the scale of the plan
>   or map.

Refer to page 6 of the referenced document for more info.

Comment: vector graphics magic